# Read all columns and change name of a column in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in Mysql. The table has more than 200 columns. I want to read all the columns, however, I have to read one of the column `(A)` as a specific name. Now, I have to use two lines of code and it take times.

```
df1 = pd.read_sql("""SELECT * FROM mytable""", db1)
df2 = pd.read_sql("""SELECT A as specific_name FROM mytable""", db1)
```

I want to ask that is anyway to use only one line of code?
Thanks

Comment: Does it matter if that column is included twice? (Once with original name A, and once as specific_name.)

Comment: No, In the first line, I don't know how to read all the column. Since I have 200 column, I can not write select column1, ..., column200 from mytable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```py
df = pd.read_sql("""SELECT T.*, T.A as specific_name FROM mytable T""", db1)
```

It should give all columns of my table and then added `specific_name` column at the end.

**Update:**

As a side note - if you have really big table (rows-wise) - you can just select all columns (don't query `specific_name`), and then rename column `A` with `df.rename(columns={"A": "specific_name"})`. Saves traffic and I would guess more elegant.

```py
df = pd.read_sql("""SELECT T.* FROM mytable T""", db1)
df.rename(columns={"A": "specific_name"})
```

Comment: @Yellowman Just added a note that might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I can answer this with 1 line of SQL and 1 line of python if that would help:

```
df2 = pd.read_sql("""SELECT A as specific_name , * FROM mytable""", db1)
df2 .drop('A', axis = 1, inplace = True)
```

This will read all of the columns form mytable into a df then once you've created your df you can simply drop the 'A' column since you renamed it to something else anyways.